ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qutip.nonmarkov'
how to solve this error? what is that changed in the new v5.0.1.
from qutip.nonmarkov.heom import HEOMSolver

# Define the bath and coupling
gamma = 0.05  # Damping rate
temperature = 0.1  # in units where kB = 1
bath = BosonicBath(gamma, temperature)

# Setup the solver
solver = HEOMSolver(H, [bath])

# Solve the dynamics
tlist = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
result = solver.run(psi0, tlist)

I tried to run the solver

For importing HEOMSolver in version 5, you need to use qutip.solver instead:
from qutip.solver.heom import HEOMSolver

Also see documentation for qutip 5.0
